# How to filter Pandas dataframe by a partial label

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Can you please suggest me a way to filter the first three comments of user_id = 101 whose label = 1 without touching the comments with label = 0. I need to preserve the order too. Appreciate your help.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = np.array([['user_id','comment','label'],
            [100,'First comment',0],
            [101,'Buy viagra',1],
            [102,'Second comment',0],
            [101,'Third comment',0],
            [103,'Fourth comment',0],
            [101,'Buy drugs',1],
            [104,'Fifth comment',0],
            [101,'Buy icecream',1],
            [105,'Sixth comment',0],
            [101,'Buy something',1]])
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data[1:,0:],columns = data[0,0:])
```

I am looking for the following output:

```
 0     100    First comment     0
 1     101       Buy viagra     1
 2     102   Second comment     0
 3     101    Third comment     0
 4     103   Fourth comment     0
 5     101        Buy drugs     1
 6     104    Fifth comment     0
 7     101     Buy icecream     1
 8     105    Sixth comment     0
```

I tried taking the first three comments of user_id = 101 by

```
 q = df.groupby('user_id').head(3)
```

But obviously this just takes the first 3 comments irrespective of the label and gives me an incorrect result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a boolean mask, and filter accordingly, using boolean indexing/`loc`/`isin`/`query`/`eval`.

```
m = m = df.user_id.eq('101') & df.label.eq('1')

i = df[m].head(3)
j = df[~m]

df = pd.concat([i, j]).sort_index()
df

  user_id         comment label
0     100   First comment     0
1     101      Buy viagra     1
2     102  Second comment     0
3     101   Third comment     0
4     103  Fourth comment     0
5     101       Buy drugs     1
6     104   Fifth comment     0
7     101    Buy icecream     1
8     105   Sixth comment     0
```

The advantage of this process of filtering is that you preserve the index, so a subsequent `sort_index` call fixes the ordering once you join the two pieces together.

Comment: Hey, I am actually looking for a different output with four comments of user_id = 101 (first three with label = 1 and I should ignore those with label = 0). Desired output is in the question. Any idea how? Thanks!

Comment: @Chandan Then maybe you needed `m = df.user_id.eq('101') & df.label.eq(1)`?

Comment: @Chandan Yes, that is indeed what you needed. Please use strings or integers depending on your actual data, but besides that, I think this solves your query.

Comment: @COLDSPEED I am getting the exact input as output by doing that. Not sure why.

Comment: @Chandan Sorry I didn't make that clear to you, this is not an in place operation. Assign it back (see edit)

Comment: Got it! Used string and that fixed it! Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163025/discussion-between-chandan-and-cs).